# Could not open input file: composer.phar while new laravel project is created

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, composer

I have installed composer globally using the steps mentioned in https://getcomposer.org/

But after installing Laravel framework, when I create a new laravel project, the following error is thrown.

```
Could not open input file: composer.phar
```

But the project gets initialized in the back. What is the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was while installing the composer was installed both globally as well as locally and due to this the referencing issue rose. After the local installation was removed, the project was successfully installed with all the dependencies.